# How to enable flycheck in every layer in spacemacs by default?

Tags: spacemacs

I have syntax-checking in my layers, and according to the documentation, it should be enabled by default in every buffer. However, for me this is not the case. How do I enable flyspell syntax-checking by default in spacemacs?

Comment: Your code to enable flycheck in all modes? Have you added (global-flycheck-mode) to your emacs config?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. Even doing M-x global-flycheck-mode disables correctly but doesn't enable.

Comment: (global-flycheck-mode 1) to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x customize-variable RET global-flycheck-mode` and set to `non-nil`.

`M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-global-modes` and set to `all`.

Make sure you hit `Apply and Save`.